# Help with a fairly simple MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to pull up some data.

**Here is the setup:**

A [school] can have multiple [semester].  Only one [semester] can be *active* per [school].

**The simplified fields per table:**

- [school] has 'id','title'
- [school_semester] has 'id','school_id' (fk), 'semester_id' (fk), '**active**', 'start_date', 'end_date'
- [semester] has 'id', 'title'

The "school_semester" table holds information for it's specific school/semester. (startdate,enddate,etc).

Anyway, I am simply trying to pull up all schools, and in this query I want to also see that school's current active semester.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT *, `school`.`name` as school_name
FROM (`school`)
LEFT JOIN `school_semester` ON `school`.`id` = `school_semester`.`school_id`
LEFT JOIN `semester` ON `semester`.`id` = `school_semester`.`semester_id`
ORDER BY `school_semester`.`active`
```

**The problem:**

This works if a school has semester that is active, but if it does not, it will show one which may be marked as inactive. If I add the statement WHERE `school_semester`.`active` = 1, it excludes schools that do not have an active semester..

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the condition on the joining :

```
SELECT *, `school`.`name` as school_name
FROM (`school`)
LEFT JOIN `school_semester` ON 
        `school`.`id` = `school_semester`.`school_id` AND
        `school_semester`.`active`
LEFT JOIN `semester` ON `semester`.`id` = `school_semester`.`semester_id`
```

This way, only the active semesters will be joined to the result.

Comment: i think Joe's answer is pretty much the same as yours, but does "AND `school_semester`.`active`" mean the same thing as "AND `school_semester`.`active` = 1"  ?

Comment: There's a good chance the statement will be equals. But since active is probably a boolean, there's no need to compare it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Add `active=1` as part of your join condition.

```
SELECT *, `school`.`name` as school_name
FROM (`school`)
LEFT JOIN `school_semester` ON `school`.`id` = `school_semester`.`school_id`
    AND `school_semester`.`active` = 1
LEFT JOIN `semester` ON `semester`.`id` = `school_semester`.`semester_id`
ORDER BY `school_semester`.`active`
```

Comment: didnt know you could do this inside the join statement :) you learn every day